# Javascript not working on ipad (tested on ios 13.7 and ios 14.0 - in chrome, safari and firefox) or iphone (tested on iphone SE ios 13.7)

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, show-hide

I wonder if you can help me please? I am trying to get a a piece of javascript to work on ios devices. I have multiple images on a page in divs and on click I would like to slide across a panel of information (hidden to the left) and once that panel slides in, if that panel is clicked, I would like it to slide back out to the left.

Here is the code I have that works perfectly on all desktop browsers but doesn't do a thing on ios - I can't understand it and am uncertain how to test or check for problems on ios.

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adpLqbt2/31/

CSS

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

.overlay-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: url('../img/icons/info.svg') 98% 98% no-repeat;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


.over-show {
  left: 0;
  height: 500px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

HTML

```
           <div class="box">
            <div class="overlay-btn"></div>
            <div class="overlay-content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="rah" />
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="overlay-btn"></div>
            <div class="overlay-content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="yay" />
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="overlay-btn"></div>
            <div class="overlay-content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="see" />
          </div>
```

JS

```
const triggers = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-btn');
const triggerArray = Array.from(triggers).entries();
const panels = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-content');
const infoButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-btn');

for (let [index, trigger] of triggerArray) {
  let triggerIndex = index;
  function togglePanel() {
    panels[triggerIndex].classList.toggle('over-show');
    infoButtons[triggerIndex].classList.toggle('js-fade');
  }
  trigger.addEventListener('click', togglePanel);
  infoButtons[triggerIndex].addEventListener('click', togglePanel);
}
```

Comment: You can debug from the desktop Safari your JS code that runs on iOS Simulator.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I did what you suggested and I'm getting this message: 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: triggerIndex' - Could you please help me understand what I need to do based on the above JS code and Pen? As I said earlier, it's working find on all desktop browsers. Very strange... Thanks James

Comment: I believe you should debug it by yourself. You can set breakpoints in the Web inspector of desktop Safari while debugging the iOS Simulator, also you can print to the console or show alerts :) From what I can tell briefly, it might be that JS is invoked before the DOM gets loaded, so that there is no `overlay-bin` yet there.